# How to wrap image over an 3d object in ARkIt2?

Tags: ios, iphone, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I need to wrap the 3d object (`scene`) with an image. Something like this:

[image]

I am using the following code:

```
let imageMaterial = SCNMaterial()
let image = UIImage(named: "temp_flow_image")
imageMaterial.diffuse.contents = image

let objectScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/frame.scn")
    let objectNode: SCNNode = objectScene!.rootNode.childNode(withName: "frame", recursively: true)! 
objectNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = imageMaterial

objectNode.position = SCNVector3(0,0,-4)

let scene = SCNScene() // Main scene of the app
self.sceneView.scene = objectScene!
```

The whole process would be like this:

Load the `3d` object as a `SCNNode` and wrap the image around it programmatically. I can see the 3d object but not the image over it. What I am doing wrong here? Can't we edit the geometry part of `scene` pragmatically?

I can wrap the image around `SCNBox` or any other predefined shape in `arkit` but not with the external `3d` object

Comment: have you tried like this objectNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "temp_flow_image")

Comment: yes, already tried it. Please check the code

Comment: In frame.scn file go to material -> property -> shading, In sahding change physically based to blinn

Comment: can you share screenshot of materail properties of scn file

Comment: Please checkout the answer

Comment: great!!! upvoted..

Answer (score 1):

Following code is working :

```
self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (node, _) in
if(node.name == "box") {
   parentNode = node
   let geometry = parentNode.geometry
   geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = imageToDisplay
   parentNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, -2.9)
   let boxShape:SCNPhysicsShape = SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: geometry!, options: nil)
            parentNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .static, shape: boxShape)
            parentNode.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
        }
    }

 sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(parentNode)
```

I created `scene box` in Xcode